# Printing upside down Triangle in c

Tags: c

The following code is supposed to print a rectangle created from right triangles of numbers and astrics but my code only prints out the numbers but its not printing out the astrics like the example bellow.

```
int x,y,z;

for (x=1; x<=10; x++)
  for (y=1; y<=x; y++)
     printf("%d", y);
  for (z=0; z<i, ++z)
     printf("*");
```

This is the example of what the above code is supped to print.

```
1*******
12******
123*****
1234****
12345***
123456**
1234567*
```

Comment: What value are you assigning to `i` in your asterisk logic?

Comment: use braces. ALLWAYES!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code a little:

```
int x,y,z;

for (x=1; x<=10; x++){
  for (y=1; y<=x; y++) printf("%d", y);
  for (z=y; z<=10; ++z) printf("*");
  printf("\n");
}
```

y and z loops should be in one code block to achieve the result; you'd also need newline after each line of numbers and asterisks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been trying for hours now and it turns out was a simple fix. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is efficient code with 2 loops:

```
for(r=0; r<7; r++)
{
    for(c=0; c<8; c++)
    {
        if(c<=r)
        {
            printf("%d", c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("*");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```